# convert double latin letters to US7ASCII

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

How can i convert **Æ**`(latin capital letter ae)` to **AE**`(US7ASCII)` in  oracle.I have tried with following query below:

```
SELECT CONVERT ('Æ', 'US7ASCII') FROM DUAL;
```

But it gives me **?** as output ,but the same query is working for single characters as shown below:

```
SELECT CONVERT ('à', 'US7ASCII') FROM DUAL;

OUTPUT
==========
 a
==========
```

Comment: Are you attempting to migrate from one character set to another? Why would `REPLACE` not work?

Comment: @AdamHawkes:I don't want to hardcode :(

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of data in a character set other than ASCII and want to convert it all to ASCII. In order to do this more automatically, you would need to become intimately familiar with [Customizing a Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch13custlocale.htm) so that CONVERT knows how you want the conversions to be done. Yes, that would mean hardcoding the conversions you want, but only once instead of for each operation you want to do.

In general, you will probably not be happy converting these characters. Things like "Æ" converting to "AE" and "ß" converting to "SS" or "SZ" will likely lead to frustration in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

US7ASCII is a 7bit character set. Probably you don't have the character "Æ" among those 128 characters. So it is not possible.

Comment: :So what is the solution for such set of data , i don't want to hardcode this .i have a string `Ææßáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ` and i don't know how to do this without hardcoding

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: :I just want to convert double character set to normal english character like `Æ` to `AE`and there are many more